# Exact JSON creation using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm currently working on some sort of Information Visualization that consists of displaying binary tree over web in my website http://codemink.com

For this, I'm using this library: http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html

This is the main code structure of above example.

```
//init data
var json = "{id:\"node02\", name:\"0.2\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node13\", name:\"1.3\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node24\", name:\"2.4\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node35\", name:\"3.5\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node46\", name:\"4.6\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node37\", name:\"3.7\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node48\", name:\"4.8\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node49\", name:\"4.9\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node410\", name:\"4.10\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node411\", name:\"4.11\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node312\", name:\"3.12\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node413\", name:\"4.13\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node314\", name:\"3.14\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node415\", name:\"4.15\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node416\", name:\"4.16\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node417\", name:\"4.17\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node418\", name:\"4.18\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node319\", name:\"3.19\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node420\", name:\"4.20\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node421\", name:\"4.21\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node222\", name:\"2.22\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node323\", name:\"3.23\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node424\", name:\"4.24\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}]}, {id:\"node125\", name:\"1.25\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node226\", name:\"2.26\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node327\", name:\"3.27\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node428\", name:\"4.28\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node429\", name:\"4.29\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node330\", name:\"3.30\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node431\", name:\"4.31\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node332\", name:\"3.32\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node433\", name:\"4.33\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node434\", name:\"4.34\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node435\", name:\"4.35\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node436\", name:\"4.36\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node237\", name:\"2.37\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node338\", name:\"3.38\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node439\", name:\"4.39\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node440\", name:\"4.40\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node441\", name:\"4.41\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node342\", name:\"3.42\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node443\", name:\"4.43\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node344\", name:\"3.44\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node445\", name:\"4.45\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node446\", name:\"4.46\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node447\", name:\"4.47\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node348\", name:\"3.48\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node449\", name:\"4.49\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node450\", name:\"4.50\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node451\", name:\"4.51\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node452\", name:\"4.52\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node453\", name:\"4.53\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node354\", name:\"3.54\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node455\", name:\"4.55\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node456\", name:\"4.56\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node457\", name:\"4.57\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node258\", name:\"2.58\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node359\", name:\"3.59\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node460\", name:\"4.60\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node461\", name:\"4.61\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node462\", name:\"4.62\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node463\", name:\"4.63\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node464\", name:\"4.64\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}]}, {id:\"node165\", name:\"1.65\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node266\", name:\"2.66\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node367\", name:\"3.67\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node468\", name:\"4.68\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node469\", name:\"4.69\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node470\", name:\"4.70\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node471\", name:\"4.71\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node372\", name:\"3.72\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node473\", name:\"4.73\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node474\", name:\"4.74\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node475\", name:\"4.75\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node476\", name:\"4.76\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node377\", name:\"3.77\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node478\", name:\"4.78\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node479\", name:\"4.79\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node380\", name:\"3.80\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node481\", name:\"4.81\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node482\", name:\"4.82\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node283\", name:\"2.83\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node384\", name:\"3.84\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node485\", name:\"4.85\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node386\", name:\"3.86\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node487\", name:\"4.87\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node488\", name:\"4.88\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node489\", name:\"4.89\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node490\", name:\"4.90\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node491\", name:\"4.91\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node392\", name:\"3.92\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node493\", name:\"4.93\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node494\", name:\"4.94\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node495\", name:\"4.95\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node496\", name:\"4.96\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node397\", name:\"3.97\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node498\", name:\"4.98\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node399\", name:\"3.99\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4100\", name:\"4.100\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4101\", name:\"4.101\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4102\", name:\"4.102\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4103\", name:\"4.103\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node2104\", name:\"2.104\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node3105\", name:\"3.105\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4106\", name:\"4.106\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4107\", name:\"4.107\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4108\", name:\"4.108\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node2109\", name:\"2.109\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node3110\", name:\"3.110\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4111\", name:\"4.111\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4112\", name:\"4.112\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node3113\", name:\"3.113\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4114\", name:\"4.114\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4115\", name:\"4.115\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4116\", name:\"4.116\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node3117\", name:\"3.117\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4118\", name:\"4.118\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4119\", name:\"4.119\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4120\", name:\"4.120\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4121\", name:\"4.121\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node3122\", name:\"3.122\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4123\", name:\"4.123\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4124\", name:\"4.124\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node2125\", name:\"2.125\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node3126\", name:\"3.126\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4127\", name:\"4.127\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4128\", name:\"4.128\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4129\", name:\"4.129\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}]}, {id:\"node1130\", name:\"1.130\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node2131\", name:\"2.131\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node3132\", name:\"3.132\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4133\", name:\"4.133\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4134\", name:\"4.134\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4135\", name:\"4.135\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4136\", name:\"4.136\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4137\", name:\"4.137\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}, {id:\"node2138\", name:\"2.138\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node3139\", name:\"3.139\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4140\", name:\"4.140\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4141\", name:\"4.141\", data:{}, children:[]}]}, {id:\"node3142\", name:\"3.142\", data:{}, children:[{id:\"node4143\", name:\"4.143\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4144\", name:\"4.144\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4145\", name:\"4.145\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4146\", name:\"4.146\", data:{}, children:[]}, {id:\"node4147\", name:\"4.147\", data:{}, children:[]}]}]}]}]}";
//end

//A client-side tree generator
var getTree = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function(nodeId, level) {
      var subtree = eval('(' + json.replace(/id:\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\"/g, 
      function(all, match) {
        return "id:\"" + match + "_" + i + "\""  
      }) + ')');
      $jit.json.prune(subtree, level); i++;
      return {
          'id': nodeId,
          'children': subtree.children
      };
    };
})();
```

The problem is JSON. I'm trying to bring this JSON data from PHP using AJAX. and this is what I'm trying to do in PHP:

```
<?php
$json = '{
"aaa":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5,
"fff":{"a":11111,"b":222222,"c":33333,"d":444454,"e":55555555},
"last":[
      {
        id: 8817,
        name: "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        id: 2873,
        name: "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        id: 1501,
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
}';


$php = json_decode($json, true);
echo var_export($php);

?>
```

and that's not working. Please help.!

Comment: `var json = "{id:\"node02\"...`  -- it's not json. At least not valid.

Comment: `{
        id: 8817,
        name: "NEW YORK CITY"
      },` --- it's not a valid json either

Comment: But, that's working. I think it's just a simple string and it's decoded in below mentioned code:

Comment: var subtree = eval('(' + json.replace(/id:\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\"/g, 
      function(all, match) {
        return "id:\"" + match + "_" + i + "\""  
      })

Comment: `eval()` treats a string as a javascript code. So if it works - it means that it's a valid JS code, but doesn't mean it's a valid json.

Comment: hmm.. So, can you suggest me any alternate ? I just want that data to come from php.

Comment: @LavneetSharma ignore if you have already tried.... You can create `PHP array` with required structure and then **`json_encode($array)`** it in the `PHP` file which you are calling through `Ajax` request

Comment: @yoesh: I just want each node having- id & name
Can you please suggest me how can i do this in php ?

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` and `json_decode` example

In `$json` you have correct JSON string - made by PHP

```
<?php

$data = array(
    "aaa" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3,
    "d" => 4,
    "e" => 5,
    "fff" => array(
        "a" => 11111,
        "b" => 222222,
        "c" => 33333,
        "d" => 444454,
        "e" => 55555555
    ),
    "last" => array(
      array(
        "id" =>  8817,
        "name" =>  "NEW YORK CITY"
      ),
      array(
        "id" =>  2873,
        "name" =>  "UNITED STATES"
      ),
      array(
        "id" =>  1501,
        "loc" =>  "NEW YORK STATE"
      )
    )
);


$json = json_encode($data);
echo '<pre>', $json ,'</pre>';

$data_again = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>', print_r($data_again) ,'</pre>';

?>
```